# Dojo DataGrid vertical Scroll backwards

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using Dojo framework to create datagrid. After the page and grid loads, select any row. Click and long press vertical scroll, you could see the vertical scroll bar scroll backwards. This issue occurs only for the first time. I know, this is weird. But I would like to know what was causing this particular issue.
Please try with the below HTML code,

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Demo: dojox/grid/DataGrid Simple Structure</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css" />
<style>
#grid {
 width: 560px;
 height: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<h1>Demo: dojox/grid/DataGrid Simple Structure</h1>

<br/>
<div id="grid"></div>

<!-- load dojo -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>
 var gridData = {
 "items": [
  {
   "bats": "R", 
   "birthDate": "1934-2-5", 
   "deathDate": null, 
   "debut": "4/13/1954 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "10/3/1976 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Hank", 
   "height": 72.0, 
   "id": "aaronha01", 
   "last": "Aaron", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Hammer,Hammerin' Hank,Bad Henry", 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 624, 
   "total3B": 98, 
   "totalAB": 12364, 
   "totalBB": 1402, 
   "totalCS": 73, 
   "totalG": 3298, 
   "totalGAB": 3298, 
   "totalGIDP": 328, 
   "totalH": 3771, 
   "totalHBP": 32, 
   "totalHR": 755, 
   "totalIBB": 293, 
   "totalK": 1383, 
   "totalR": 2174, 
   "totalRBI": 2297, 
   "totalSB": 240, 
   "totalSF": 121, 
   "totalSH": 21, 
   "weight": 180.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "R", 
   "birthDate": "1887-2-26", 
   "deathDate": "1950-11-4", 
   "debut": "4/15/1911 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "5/28/1930 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Pete", 
   "height": 73.0, 
   "id": "alexape01", 
   "last": "Alexander", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Old Pete", 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 60, 
   "total3B": 13, 
   "totalAB": 1810, 
   "totalBB": 77, 
   "totalCS": 5, 
   "totalG": 703, 
   "totalGAB": 703, 
   "totalGIDP": null, 
   "totalH": 378, 
   "totalHBP": 2, 
   "totalHR": 11, 
   "totalIBB": null, 
   "totalK": 276, 
   "totalR": 154, 
   "totalRBI": 163, 
   "totalSB": 3, 
   "totalSF": null, 
   "totalSH": 88, 
   "weight": 185.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "R", 
   "birthDate": "1852-4-17", 
   "deathDate": "1922-4-14", 
   "debut": "5/6/1871 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "10/3/1897 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Cap", 
   "height": 72.0, 
   "id": "ansonca01", 
   "last": "Anson", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Pop", 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 581, 
   "total3B": 142, 
   "totalAB": 10277, 
   "totalBB": 983, 
   "totalCS": 16, 
   "totalG": 2523, 
   "totalGAB": 2523, 
   "totalGIDP": null, 
   "totalH": 3418, 
   "totalHBP": 32, 
   "totalHR": 97, 
   "totalIBB": null, 
   "totalK": 302, 
   "totalR": 1996, 
   "totalRBI": 2076, 
   "totalSB": 276, 
   "totalSF": null, 
   "totalSH": 27, 
   "weight": 227.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "R", 
   "birthDate": "1934-4-29", 
   "deathDate": null, 
   "debut": "4/17/1956 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "9/28/1973 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Luis", 
   "height": 69.0, 
   "id": "aparilu01", 
   "last": "Aparicio", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Little Louie", 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 394, 
   "total3B": 92, 
   "totalAB": 10230, 
   "totalBB": 736, 
   "totalCS": 136, 
   "totalG": 2601, 
   "totalGAB": 2601, 
   "totalGIDP": 184, 
   "totalH": 2677, 
   "totalHBP": 27, 
   "totalHR": 83, 
   "totalIBB": 22, 
   "totalK": 742, 
   "totalR": 1335, 
   "totalRBI": 791, 
   "totalSB": 506, 
   "totalSF": 76, 
   "totalSH": 161, 
   "weight": 160.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "R", 
   "birthDate": "1907-4-2", 
   "deathDate": "1991-1-3", 
   "debut": "9/10/1930 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "10/1/1950 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Luke", 
   "height": 70.0, 
   "id": "applilu01", 
   "last": "Appling", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Old Aches and Pains,Luscious Luke", 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 440, 
   "total3B": 102, 
   "totalAB": 8856, 
   "totalBB": 1302, 
   "totalCS": 108, 
   "totalG": 2422, 
   "totalGAB": 2422, 
   "totalGIDP": 129, 
   "totalH": 2749, 
   "totalHBP": 11, 
   "totalHR": 45, 
   "totalIBB": null, 
   "totalK": 528, 
   "totalR": 1319, 
   "totalRBI": 1116, 
   "totalSB": 179, 
   "totalSF": null, 
   "totalSH": 74, 
   "weight": 183.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "L", 
   "birthDate": "1927-3-19", 
   "deathDate": "1997-9-9", 
   "debut": "4/20/1948 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "9/30/1962 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Richie", 
   "height": 70.0, 
   "id": "ashburi01", 
   "last": "Ashburn", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Whitey,Put Put", 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 317, 
   "total3B": 109, 
   "totalAB": 8365, 
   "totalBB": 1198, 
   "totalCS": 92, 
   "totalG": 2189, 
   "totalGAB": 2189, 
   "totalGIDP": 83, 
   "totalH": 2574, 
   "totalHBP": 43, 
   "totalHR": 29, 
   "totalIBB": 25, 
   "totalK": 571, 
   "totalR": 1322, 
   "totalRBI": 586, 
   "totalSB": 234, 
   "totalSF": 18, 
   "totalSH": 112, 
   "weight": 170.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "L", 
   "birthDate": "1902-5-21", 
   "deathDate": "1983-8-16", 
   "debut": "4/16/1929 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "4/25/1941 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Earl", 
   "height": 69.0, 
   "id": "averiea01", 
   "last": "Averill", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Rock,The Earl of Snohomish", 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 401, 
   "total3B": 128, 
   "totalAB": 6353, 
   "totalBB": 774, 
   "totalCS": 57, 
   "totalG": 1668, 
   "totalGAB": 1668, 
   "totalGIDP": 7, 
   "totalH": 2019, 
   "totalHBP": 33, 
   "totalHR": 238, 
   "totalIBB": null, 
   "totalK": 518, 
   "totalR": 1224, 
   "totalRBI": 1164, 
   "totalSB": 70, 
   "totalSF": null, 
   "totalSH": 55, 
   "weight": 172.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "L", 
   "birthDate": "1886-3-13", 
   "deathDate": "1963-6-28", 
   "debut": "9/21/1908 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "9/29/1922 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Frank", 
   "height": 71.0, 
   "id": "bakerfr01", 
   "last": "Baker", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Home Run", 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 315, 
   "total3B": 103, 
   "totalAB": 5984, 
   "totalBB": 473, 
   "totalCS": 28, 
   "totalG": 1575, 
   "totalGAB": 1575, 
   "totalGIDP": null, 
   "totalH": 1838, 
   "totalHBP": 50, 
   "totalHR": 96, 
   "totalIBB": null, 
   "totalK": 182, 
   "totalR": 887, 
   "totalRBI": 987, 
   "totalSB": 235, 
   "totalSF": null, 
   "totalSH": 153, 
   "weight": 173.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "B", 
   "birthDate": "1891-4-20", 
   "deathDate": "1972-10-9", 
   "debut": "4/14/1915 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "5/31/1930 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Dave", 
   "height": 69.0, 
   "id": "bancrda01", 
   "last": "Bancroft", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Beauty", 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 320, 
   "total3B": 77, 
   "totalAB": 7182, 
   "totalBB": 827, 
   "totalCS": 75, 
   "totalG": 1913, 
   "totalGAB": 1913, 
   "totalGIDP": null, 
   "totalH": 2004, 
   "totalHBP": 23, 
   "totalHR": 32, 
   "totalIBB": null, 
   "totalK": 487, 
   "totalR": 1048, 
   "totalRBI": 591, 
   "totalSB": 145, 
   "totalSF": null, 
   "totalSH": 212, 
   "weight": 160.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "R", 
   "birthDate": "1931-1-31", 
   "deathDate": null, 
   "debut": "9/17/1953 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "9/26/1971 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Ernie", 
   "height": 73.0, 
   "id": "bankser01", 
   "last": "Banks", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Mr. Cub", 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 407, 
   "total3B": 90, 
   "totalAB": 9421, 
   "totalBB": 763, 
   "totalCS": 53, 
   "totalG": 2528, 
   "totalGAB": 2528, 
   "totalGIDP": 229, 
   "totalH": 2583, 
   "totalHBP": 70, 
   "totalHR": 512, 
   "totalIBB": 198, 
   "totalK": 1236, 
   "totalR": 1305, 
   "totalRBI": 1636, 
   "totalSB": 50, 
   "totalSF": 96, 
   "totalSH": 45, 
   "weight": 180.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "L", 
   "birthDate": "1867-8-4", 
   "deathDate": "1918-6-25", 
   "debut": "6/20/1888 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "6/15/1907 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Jake", 
   "height": 70.0, 
   "id": "becklja01", 
   "last": "Beckley", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Eagle Eye", 
   "throws": "L", 
   "total2B": 473, 
   "total3B": 243, 
   "totalAB": 9526, 
   "totalBB": 616, 
   "totalCS": null, 
   "totalG": 2386, 
   "totalGAB": 2386, 
   "totalGIDP": null, 
   "totalH": 2930, 
   "totalHBP": 183, 
   "totalHR": 86, 
   "totalIBB": null, 
   "totalK": 270, 
   "totalR": 1600, 
   "totalRBI": 1575, 
   "totalSB": 315, 
   "totalSF": null, 
   "totalSH": 145, 
   "weight": 200.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "R", 
   "birthDate": "1947-12-7", 
   "deathDate": null, 
   "debut": "8/28/1967 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "9/29/1983 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Johnny", 
   "height": 73.0, 
   "id": "benchjo01", 
   "last": "Bench", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Little General", 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 381, 
   "total3B": 24, 
   "totalAB": 7658, 
   "totalBB": 891, 
   "totalCS": 43, 
   "totalG": 2158, 
   "totalGAB": 2158, 
   "totalGIDP": 201, 
   "totalH": 2048, 
   "totalHBP": 19, 
   "totalHR": 389, 
   "totalIBB": 135, 
   "totalK": 1278, 
   "totalR": 1091, 
   "totalRBI": 1376, 
   "totalSB": 68, 
   "totalSF": 90, 
   "totalSH": 11, 
   "weight": 197.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "R", 
   "birthDate": "1884-5-5", 
   "deathDate": "1954-5-22", 
   "debut": "4/20/1903 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "7/21/1925 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Chief", 
   "height": 74.0, 
   "id": "bendech01", 
   "last": "Bender", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": null, 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 40, 
   "total3B": 10, 
   "totalAB": 1147, 
   "totalBB": 75, 
   "totalCS": 0, 
   "totalG": 507, 
   "totalGAB": 507, 
   "totalGIDP": 0, 
   "totalH": 243, 
   "totalHBP": 10, 
   "totalHR": 6, 
   "totalIBB": 0, 
   "totalK": 48, 
   "totalR": 102, 
   "totalRBI": 116, 
   "totalSB": 20, 
   "totalSF": 0, 
   "totalSH": 42, 
   "weight": 185.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "L", 
   "birthDate": "1925-5-12", 
   "deathDate": null, 
   "debut": "9/22/1946 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "5/9/1965 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Yogi", 
   "height": 67.0, 
   "id": "berrayo01", 
   "last": "Berra", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": null, 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 321, 
   "total3B": 49, 
   "totalAB": 7555, 
   "totalBB": 704, 
   "totalCS": 26, 
   "totalG": 2120, 
   "totalGAB": 2120, 
   "totalGIDP": 146, 
   "totalH": 2150, 
   "totalHBP": 52, 
   "totalHR": 358, 
   "totalIBB": 49, 
   "totalK": 414, 
   "totalR": 1175, 
   "totalRBI": 1430, 
   "totalSB": 30, 
   "totalSF": 44, 
   "totalSH": 9, 
   "weight": 185.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "L", 
   "birthDate": "1958-6-15", 
   "deathDate": null, 
   "debut": "4/10/1982 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "8/27/1999 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Wade", 
   "height": 74.0, 
   "id": "boggswa01", 
   "last": "Boggs", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": null, 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 578, 
   "total3B": 61, 
   "totalAB": 9180, 
   "totalBB": 1412, 
   "totalCS": 35, 
   "totalG": 2440, 
   "totalGAB": 2439, 
   "totalGIDP": 236, 
   "totalH": 3010, 
   "totalHBP": 23, 
   "totalHR": 118, 
   "totalIBB": 180, 
   "totalK": 745, 
   "totalR": 1513, 
   "totalRBI": 1014, 
   "totalSB": 24, 
   "totalSF": 96, 
   "totalSH": 29, 
   "weight": 190.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "L", 
   "birthDate": "1900-4-23", 
   "deathDate": "1959-12-11", 
   "debut": "8/18/1922 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "9/16/1937 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Jim", 
   "height": 72.0, 
   "id": "bottoji01", 
   "last": "Bottomley", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Sunny Jim", 
   "throws": "L", 
   "total2B": 465, 
   "total3B": 151, 
   "totalAB": 7471, 
   "totalBB": 664, 
   "totalCS": 15, 
   "totalG": 1991, 
   "totalGAB": 1991, 
   "totalGIDP": 33, 
   "totalH": 2313, 
   "totalHBP": 43, 
   "totalHR": 219, 
   "totalIBB": null, 
   "totalK": 591, 
   "totalR": 1177, 
   "totalRBI": 1422, 
   "totalSB": 58, 
   "totalSF": null, 
   "totalSH": 177, 
   "weight": 180.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "R", 
   "birthDate": "1917-7-17", 
   "deathDate": "2001-8-10", 
   "debut": "9/9/1938 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "8/24/1952 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Lou", 
   "height": 71.0, 
   "id": "boudrlo01", 
   "last": "Boudreau", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Old Shufflefoot,Handsome Lou", 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 385, 
   "total3B": 66, 
   "totalAB": 6029, 
   "totalBB": 796, 
   "totalCS": 50, 
   "totalG": 1646, 
   "totalGAB": 1646, 
   "totalGIDP": 155, 
   "totalH": 1779, 
   "totalHBP": 34, 
   "totalHR": 68, 
   "totalIBB": null, 
   "totalK": 309, 
   "totalR": 861, 
   "totalRBI": 789, 
   "totalSB": 51, 
   "totalSF": null, 
   "totalSH": 164, 
   "weight": 185.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "R", 
   "birthDate": "1879-6-11", 
   "deathDate": "1944-12-4", 
   "debut": "8/27/1897 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "10/3/1915 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Roger", 
   "height": 69.0, 
   "id": "bresnro01", 
   "last": "Bresnahan", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "The Duke Of Tralee", 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 218, 
   "total3B": 71, 
   "totalAB": 4481, 
   "totalBB": 714, 
   "totalCS": 3, 
   "totalG": 1446, 
   "totalGAB": 1446, 
   "totalGIDP": null, 
   "totalH": 1252, 
   "totalHBP": 67, 
   "totalHR": 26, 
   "totalIBB": null, 
   "totalK": 99, 
   "totalR": 682, 
   "totalRBI": 530, 
   "totalSB": 212, 
   "totalSF": null, 
   "totalSH": 112, 
   "weight": 200.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "L", 
   "birthDate": "1953-5-15", 
   "deathDate": null, 
   "debut": "8/2/1973 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "10/3/1993 0:00:00", 
   "first": "George", 
   "height": 72.0, 
   "id": "brettge01", 
   "last": "Brett", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Mullet", 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 665, 
   "total3B": 137, 
   "totalAB": 10349, 
   "totalBB": 1096, 
   "totalCS": 97, 
   "totalG": 2707, 
   "totalGAB": 2707, 
   "totalGIDP": 235, 
   "totalH": 3154, 
   "totalHBP": 33, 
   "totalHR": 317, 
   "totalIBB": 229, 
   "totalK": 908, 
   "totalR": 1583, 
   "totalRBI": 1595, 
   "totalSB": 201, 
   "totalSF": 120, 
   "totalSH": 26, 
   "weight": 185.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "L", 
   "birthDate": "1939-6-18", 
   "deathDate": null, 
   "debut": "9/10/1961 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "9/30/1979 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Lou", 
   "height": 71.0, 
   "id": "brocklo01", 
   "last": "Brock", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": null, 
   "throws": "L", 
   "total2B": 486, 
   "total3B": 141, 
   "totalAB": 10332, 
   "totalBB": 761, 
   "totalCS": 307, 
   "totalG": 2616, 
   "totalGAB": 2616, 
   "totalGIDP": 114, 
   "totalH": 3023, 
   "totalHBP": 49, 
   "totalHR": 149, 
   "totalIBB": 124, 
   "totalK": 1730, 
   "totalR": 1610, 
   "totalRBI": 900, 
   "totalSB": 938, 
   "totalSF": 46, 
   "totalSH": 47, 
   "weight": 170.0
  }, 
  {
   "bats": "L", 
   "birthDate": "1858-5-8", 
   "deathDate": "1932-8-2", 
   "debut": "6/23/1879 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "10/4/1904 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Dan", 
   "height": 74.0, 
   "id": "broutda01", 
   "last": "Brouthers", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Big Dan", 
   "throws": "L", 
   "total2B": 460, 
   "total3B": 205, 
   "totalAB": 6711, 
   "totalBB": 840, 
   "totalCS": null, 
   "totalG": 1673, 
   "totalGAB": 1673, 
   "totalGIDP": null, 
   "totalH": 2296, 
   "totalHBP": 105, 
   "totalHR": 106, 
   "totalIBB": null, 
   "totalK": 238, 
   "totalR": 1523, 
   "totalRBI": 1296, 
   "totalSB": 256, 
   "totalSF": null, 
   "totalSH": 2, 
   "weight": 207.0
  }, 
   
  {
   "bats": "R", 
   "birthDate": "1955-9-16", 
   "deathDate": null, 
   "debut": "4/5/1974 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "10/3/1993 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Robin", 
   "height": 72.0, 
   "id": "yountro01", 
   "last": "Yount", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": null, 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 583, 
   "total3B": 126, 
   "totalAB": 11008, 
   "totalBB": 966, 
   "totalCS": 105, 
   "totalG": 2856, 
   "totalGAB": 2856, 
   "totalGIDP": 217, 
   "totalH": 3142, 
   "totalHBP": 48, 
   "totalHR": 251, 
   "totalIBB": 95, 
   "totalK": 1350, 
   "totalR": 1632, 
   "totalRBI": 1406, 
   "totalSB": 271, 
   "totalSF": 123, 
   "totalSH": 104, 
   "weight": 165.0
  },
  {
   "bats": "L", 
   "birthDate": "1858-5-8", 
   "deathDate": "1932-8-2", 
   "debut": "6/23/1879 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "10/4/1904 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Dan", 
   "height": 74.0, 
   "id": "broutda01", 
   "last": "Brouthers", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Big Dan", 
   "throws": "L", 
   "total2B": 460, 
   "total3B": 205, 
   "totalAB": 6711, 
   "totalBB": 840, 
   "totalCS": null, 
   "totalG": 1673, 
   "totalGAB": 1673, 
   "totalGIDP": null, 
   "totalH": 2296, 
   "totalHBP": 105, 
   "totalHR": 106, 
   "totalIBB": null, 
   "totalK": 238, 
   "totalR": 1523, 
   "totalRBI": 1296, 
   "totalSB": 256, 
   "totalSF": null, 
   "totalSH": 2, 
   "weight": 207.0
  }, 
   
  {
   "bats": "R", 
   "birthDate": "1955-9-16", 
   "deathDate": null, 
   "debut": "4/5/1974 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "10/3/1993 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Robin", 
   "height": 72.0, 
   "id": "yountro01", 
   "last": "Yount", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": null, 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 583, 
   "total3B": 126, 
   "totalAB": 11008, 
   "totalBB": 966, 
   "totalCS": 105, 
   "totalG": 2856, 
   "totalGAB": 2856, 
   "totalGIDP": 217, 
   "totalH": 3142, 
   "totalHBP": 48, 
   "totalHR": 251, 
   "totalIBB": 95, 
   "totalK": 1350, 
   "totalR": 1632, 
   "totalRBI": 1406, 
   "totalSB": 271, 
   "totalSF": 123, 
   "totalSH": 104, 
   "weight": 165.0
  },
  {
   "bats": "L", 
   "birthDate": "1858-5-8", 
   "deathDate": "1932-8-2", 
   "debut": "6/23/1879 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "10/4/1904 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Dan", 
   "height": 74.0, 
   "id": "broutda01", 
   "last": "Brouthers", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Big Dan", 
   "throws": "L", 
   "total2B": 460, 
   "total3B": 205, 
   "totalAB": 6711, 
   "totalBB": 840, 
   "totalCS": null, 
   "totalG": 1673, 
   "totalGAB": 1673, 
   "totalGIDP": null, 
   "totalH": 2296, 
   "totalHBP": 105, 
   "totalHR": 106, 
   "totalIBB": null, 
   "totalK": 238, 
   "totalR": 1523, 
   "totalRBI": 1296, 
   "totalSB": 256, 
   "totalSF": null, 
   "totalSH": 2, 
   "weight": 207.0
  }, 
   
  {
   "bats": "R", 
   "birthDate": "1955-9-16", 
   "deathDate": null, 
   "debut": "4/5/1974 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "10/3/1993 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Robin", 
   "height": 72.0, 
   "id": "yountro01", 
   "last": "Yount", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": null, 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 583, 
   "total3B": 126, 
   "totalAB": 11008, 
   "totalBB": 966, 
   "totalCS": 105, 
   "totalG": 2856, 
   "totalGAB": 2856, 
   "totalGIDP": 217, 
   "totalH": 3142, 
   "totalHBP": 48, 
   "totalHR": 251, 
   "totalIBB": 95, 
   "totalK": 1350, 
   "totalR": 1632, 
   "totalRBI": 1406, 
   "totalSB": 271, 
   "totalSF": 123, 
   "totalSH": 104, 
   "weight": 165.0
  },
  {
   "bats": "L", 
   "birthDate": "1858-5-8", 
   "deathDate": "1932-8-2", 
   "debut": "6/23/1879 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "10/4/1904 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Dan", 
   "height": 74.0, 
   "id": "broutda01", 
   "last": "Brouthers", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": "Big Dan", 
   "throws": "L", 
   "total2B": 460, 
   "total3B": 205, 
   "totalAB": 6711, 
   "totalBB": 840, 
   "totalCS": null, 
   "totalG": 1673, 
   "totalGAB": 1673, 
   "totalGIDP": null, 
   "totalH": 2296, 
   "totalHBP": 105, 
   "totalHR": 106, 
   "totalIBB": null, 
   "totalK": 238, 
   "totalR": 1523, 
   "totalRBI": 1296, 
   "totalSB": 256, 
   "totalSF": null, 
   "totalSH": 2, 
   "weight": 207.0
  }, 
   
  {
   "bats": "R", 
   "birthDate": "1955-9-16", 
   "deathDate": null, 
   "debut": "4/5/1974 0:00:00", 
   "finalGame": "10/3/1993 0:00:00", 
   "first": "Robin", 
   "height": 72.0, 
   "id": "yountro01", 
   "last": "Yount", 
   "nameNote": null, 
   "nickname": null, 
   "throws": "R", 
   "total2B": 583, 
   "total3B": 126, 
   "totalAB": 11008, 
   "totalBB": 966, 
   "totalCS": 105, 
   "totalG": 2856, 
   "totalGAB": 2856, 
   "totalGIDP": 217, 
   "totalH": 3142, 
   "totalHBP": 48, 
   "totalHR": 251, 
   "totalIBB": 95, 
   "totalK": 1350, 
   "totalR": 1632, 
   "totalRBI": 1406, 
   "totalSB": 271, 
   "totalSF": 123, 
   "totalSH": 104, 
   "weight": 165.0
  },
  
 ]
};

 var grid, dataStore, store;
 require([
  "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
  "dojo/store/Memory",
  "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
  "dojo/request",
  "dojo/domReady!"
 ], function(DataGrid, Memory, ObjectStore,request){
   store = new Memory({ data: gridData.items });
   dataStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: store });

   grid = new DataGrid({
    store: dataStore,
    query: { id: "*" },
    structure: [
     { name: "First Name", field: "first", width: "84px" },
     { name: "Last Name", field: "last", width: "84px" },
     { name: "Bats", field: "bats", width: "70px" },
     { name: "Throws", field: "throws", width: "70px" },
     { name: "G", field: "totalG", width: "60px" },
     { name: "AB", field: "totalAB", width: "60px" },
     { name: "Games as Batter", field: "totalGAB", width: "120px" },
     { name: "R", field: "totalR", width: "60px" },
     { name: "RBI", field: "totalRBI", width: "60px" },
     { name: "BB", field: "totalBB", width: "60px" },
     { name: "K", field: "totalK", width: "60px" },
     { name: "H", field: "totalH", width: "60px" },
     { name: "2B", field: "total2B", width: "60px" },
     { name: "3B", field: "total3B", width: "60px" },
     { name: "HR", field: "totalHR", width: "60px" }
    ]
   });

   grid.placeAt("grid");
   // since we created this grid programmatically, call startup to render it
   //grid.startup();
   
   grid.startup();
   //grid.selection.setSelected(0, false);
   //grid.selection.clear();
   //grid.setScrollTop(10);
    /*grid.on('MouseUp',function(event) {
    //console.log("mouseup ==>"+grid.scrollTop);
    //console.log(document.getElementById("grid").scrollHeight);
    grid.setScrollTop(document.getElementById("grid").scrollHeight);
            });
   
   grid.on('MouseDown',function(event){
              //console.log("mousedown ==>"+grid.scrollTop);
            });

   */
  });
 

 function getSelectedRows() {
  var items = grid.selection.getSelected();
  alert(items.length);
 }
</script>
<input type="button" value="GetSelectedRows" onclick="getSelectedRows()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `dojox/grid/DataGrid` has `infinite scroll`, so, it will paginate the data as you scroll, if you check the source of `dojox/grid/DataGrid` you'll find out that it extends from `dojox/grid/_Grid` and it include the `dojox/grid/_Scroller`, the `_Scroller` register to the `onscroll` event of the `domNode` in the `init` function:

```
if(this.scrollboxNode){
    this.scrollboxNode.scrollTop = 0;
    this.scroll(0);
    this.scrollboxNode.onscroll = lang.hitch(this, 'onscroll');
}
```

the `onscroll` function is used to calculate the page to show

```
onscroll: function(){
    this.scroll(this.scrollboxNode.scrollTop);
},
scroll: function(inTop){
    this.grid.scrollTop = inTop;
    if(this.colCount){
        this.startPacify();
        this.findPage(inTop);
        var h = this.height;
        var b = this.getScrollBottom(inTop);
        for(var p=this.page, y=this.pageTop; (p<this.pageCount)&&((b<0)||(y<b)); p++){
            y += this.needPage(p, y);
        }
        this.firstVisibleRow = this.getFirstVisibleRow(this.page, this.pageTop, inTop);
        this.lastVisibleRow = this.getLastVisibleRow(p - 1, y, b);
        // indicates some page size has been updated
        if(h != this.height){
            this.repositionPages(p-1);
        }
        this.endPacify();
    }
},
```

this is the code of the functions in action, the rest are in `dojox/grid/DataGrid` and `dojox/grid/_Grid`

Hope this help to clear your mind